# How to find the package file that stores a certain symbol?

Tags: packages, symbols, files-and-directories, contexts

Is it possible to figure out in what file a certain packaged symbol lives in (assuming there is no shadowing between multiple identical symbol names)? I would like to have a function that if, given a context or a symbol from a context, opens up the relevant package file.

With `Needs` *Mathematica* automatically loads all symbols in each package file of the given context if directories are set correctly with `$Path`. It seems though that I cannot access the information **from which file** *Mathematica* pulls each symbol. It is an overkill to scan through all directories in `$Path` and through all files in each directory to find the given symbol. Is there an easier method?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this information is not stored: to load a package, *Mathematica* just opens a stream and reads from it as if it were any other sort of input. Still, good question, +1.

Comment: In old versions, this would have been a bit easier to do: one just scans the `init.m` file associated with each package group (e.g. ``Algebra` ``, ``NumericalMath` ``, ...) and looks at the `DeclarePackage[]` lines for the appropriate functions. The new way things are arranged now makes things slightly hairier.

Comment: If you follow the convention of having the context match the file name of the package wouldn't this be almost trivial?  Do you have a reason *not* to follow that convention?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If a given context (via `Needs`) pulls symbols from different files (as e.g. mentioned in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22407/89) case), than it is not a matter of convention but a matter of taste in which file the symbol is actually stored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My previous answer had heavy shortcomings and errors, so I took a deeper breath and figured out a more robust way.

The problem with `` FindFile["context`"] `` is twofold. First, it can only return the first file in a possibly long list of files adding to the same context. Second, it might not work on a context extracted from a symbol because symbol contexts might not be identical to the package name. The package specification in *Mathematica* is confusing: `` myPackage` `` means two different things:

1. FILENAME: If `` Get["myPackage`"] `` (or `Needs`) is called, *Mathematica* will interpret `myPackage` as a file path using `FindFile` to figure out the source.
2. CONTEXT: In `` BeginPackage["myPackage`"] `` (or `Begin`) and in `` myPackage`symbol ``, `mypackage` is interpreted as a namespace within the memory, and has nothing to do with files. `$Packages` and `$ContextPath` only store these contexts but not package-file-path-specifiers of point 1.

There is no guarantee, that the package name agrees with the context name. Though this is the convention, a package defined at path `.../myPackage` might not contain the line `` BeginPackage["myPackage`"] `` in it. One can easily create artificial cases where a package file at `.../package.m` (called as `` Get["package`"] ``) loads symbols like `` context`sym ``.

To be clear, **any package you design should have at least one file in it which has the same name as the context it generates**. If context and file name do not match, either the file is not found (if context is called by `Needs`, resulting in `Get::noopen` error) or context is not created (if filename is called by `Needs`, resulting in `Needs::nocont` error). Note however, that in the latter case, the file is nevertheless loaded, regardless of the expected context. The reason I say "at least one file" above is because this file then can call any other package file in the same directory (obviously with different file names) or from other directories.

So a foolproof solution to find all package files could only work if it knows the associations between filenames and contexts. To have that, package calls have to be monitored and the collected data stored. In another answer I presented [`safeGet`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42454/89) that can read a package, collect all the files that are touched by successive package calls from within and at the end removes all contexts and symbols introduced during all the calls. With `safeGet` it becomes possible to capture the necessary data to identify sources. `safeGetSource` is a light version of `safeGet` that only captures context -> file associations but not all files (like `init.m`-s that don't contain context-creating code).

```
contextJoin[s:{__String}] := StringReplace[StringJoin[#<>"`"& /@s], "`".. -> "`"]
packageButton[file_String] := Button[FileNameTake@file, NotebookOpen@file, 
   Appearance -> "Palette"];

safeGetSource[pkg_String, arg___] := Module[{
    bp, ep, begin, end, contexts = {}, assoc = {}, all, 
    cStack = {$Context}, cpStack = {$ContextPath}},
   Block[{$Packages = $Packages, $ContextPath = $ContextPath, $Context = $Context},
    Off[General::shdw];
    bp[ctx_] := bp[ctx, {}];
    bp[ctx_, needed_List] := (
      AppendTo[cStack, $Context];
      AppendTo[cpStack, $ContextPath];
      $ContextPath = DeleteDuplicates@Join[{ctx}, needed, {"System`"}];
      $Packages = DeleteDuplicates@Prepend[$Packages, ctx];
      $Context = ctx;
      assoc = Union[assoc, {$Context -> packageButton@$InputFileName}];
      contexts = Union[contexts, {$Context}];
      Needs /@ needed;
      ctx);
    begin[ctx_] := (
      AppendTo[cStack, $Context];
      $Context = contextJoin@{$Context, ctx};
      assoc = Union[assoc, {$Context -> packageButton@$InputFileName}];
      contexts = Union[contexts, {$Context}];
      ctx);
    ep[] := ({$ContextPath, cpStack} = {Last@cpStack, Most@cpStack};
             {$Context, cStack} = {Last@cStack, Most@cStack};);
    end[] := ({$Context, cStack} = {Last@cStack, Most@cStack};);
    Block[{BeginPackage=bp, EndPackage=ep, Begin=begin, End=end}, Get[pkg, arg]];
    all = # <> "*" & /@ contexts;
    Unprotect /@ all;
    Quiet[Remove /@ all];
    On[General::shdw];
    assoc
    ]];

assoc = safeGetSource@"OpenCLLink`"
```

> ```
> {
>  "CCompilerDriver`" -> "CCompilerDriver.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`" -> "CCompilerDriverBase.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverBase`Private`" -> "CCompilerDriverBase.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverRegistry`" -> "CCompilerDriverRegistry.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`CCompilerDriverRegistry`Private`" -> "CCompilerDriverRegistry.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`" -> "GenericCCompiler.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`Private`" -> "GenericCCompiler.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`IntelCompiler`" -> "IntelCompiler.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`IntelCompilerWindows`" -> "IntelCompilerWindows.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`IntelCompilerWindows`Private`" -> "IntelCompilerWindows.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`Private`" -> "CCompilerDriver.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`System`" -> "System.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`System`Private`" -> "System.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`" -> "VisualStudioCompiler.m",
>  "CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`Private`" -> "VisualStudioCompiler.m",
>  "CUDALink`" -> "CUDALink.m",
>  "CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`" -> "NVCCCompiler.m",
>  "CUDALink`NVCCCompiler`Private`" -> "NVCCCompiler.m",
>  "CUDALink`Private`" -> "CUDALink.m",
>  "GPUTools`" -> "GPUTools.m",
>  "GPUTools`CodeGenerator`" -> "CodeGenerator.m",
>  "GPUTools`CodeGenerator`Private`" -> "CodeGenerator.m",
>  "GPUTools`Detection`" -> "Detection.m",
>  "GPUTools`Detection`Private`" -> "Detection.m",
>  "GPUTools`Private`" -> "GPUTools.m",
>  "GPUTools`SymbolicGPU`" -> "SymbolicGPU.m",
>  "GPUTools`SymbolicGPU`Private`" -> "SymbolicGPU.m",
>  "GPUTools`Utilities`" -> "Utilities.m",
>  "GPUTools`Utilities`Private`" -> "Utilities.m",
>  "LibraryLink`" -> "LibraryLink.m",
>  "LibraryLink`Private`" -> "LibraryLink.m",
>  "OpenCLLink`" -> "OpenCLLink.m",
>  "OpenCLLink`Private`" -> "OpenCLLink.m",
>  "SymbolicC`" -> "SymbolicC.m",
>  "SymbolicC`Private`" -> "SymbolicC.m"
> }
> ```

Querying a symbol can now be done as:

```
 Context@symbol /. assoc
```

Examining `"PacletManager`"`` reveals that the one public context calls quite a few files:

```
 safeGetSource@"PacletManager`"
```

> ```
> {
>  "PacletManager`" -> "PacletManager.m",
>  "PacletManager`Collection`Private`" -> "Collection.m",
>  "PacletManager`Documentation`Private`" -> "Documentation.m",
>  "PacletManager`Extension`Private`" -> "Extension.m",
>  "PacletManager`LayoutDocsCollection`Private`" -> "LayoutDocsCollection.m",
>  "PacletManager`Manager`Private`" -> "Manager.m",
>  "PacletManager`MemoryCollection`Private`" -> "MemoryCollection.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Collection.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Documentation.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Extension.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "LayoutDocsCollection.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Manager.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "MemoryCollection.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Packer.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Paclet.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "PacletManager.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Services.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Utils.m",
>  "PacletManager`Package`" -> "Zip.m",
>  "PacletManager`Packer`Private`" -> "Packer.m",
>  "PacletManager`Paclet`Private`" -> "Paclet.m",
>  "PacletManager`Private`" -> "PacletManager.m",
>  "PacletManager`Services`Private`" -> "Services.m",
>  "PacletManager`Utils`Private`" -> "Utils.m",
>  "PacletManager`Zip`Private`" -> "Zip.m"
> }
> ```

Let's see a less complicated example, with a non-conventional package-context association (made for this purpose). Note, that while the package was called as `` "MyPackage`" ``, the context added to memory and captured by `safeGetSource` is `` "MyContext`" ``:

```
 safeGetSource@"MyPackage`"
```

> ```
> {
>  "Functions`" -> "Functions.m",
>  "Functions`Private`" -> "Functions.m",
>  "MyContext`" -> "file.m",
>  "Test`" -> "Common.m",
>  "Test`" -> "TestA.m",
>  "Test`" -> "TestB.m",
>  "Test`Private`" -> "TestA.m",
>  "Test`Private`" -> "TestB.m"
> }
> ```

The dependency tree of the above call, created by `safeGet`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'll admit that I didn't try to understand how it works, I just tried it on the package I wanted to do this with last time: ``safeGet["OpenCLLink`"]``.  Unfortunately it seems to go into an infinite recursion.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for taking the time to test it! The previous code was crap, please check new version.

Comment: In `contextJoin` (first line in code box), `str` should be corrected to `s`, right?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sure, thanks, corrected. Made the line shorter to fit the page width but forgot to replace all vars.

Comment: Would you like to submit a patch to the spelunking package to add this (and related) functionality?  (This would be a separate function, but part of the same package.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, I will gladly add to it! Just want to test it a bit further and see how people test it. Some bugs surely will surface...

Comment: @Szabolcs I might have considered your offer more seriously than necessary. In the last weeks I was busy to combine functionality of three domains: packages-and-contexts, symbols and definitions, as these are used all the time during development. I now have working code in all three. I would like to discuss it with you how it should be published, as I it nicely fits spelunking, but is more than what that package aims for. Would you have time to meet me in chat sometimes to revise the code and decide on how to introduce it to the community? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Let's do it tomorrow some time after 18:30 Budapest time ... I'm teaching tomorrow so I need to prepare for that today.  But you can consider a completely separate package as well.  After all this functionality would be separate from spelunking (it would not depend on it) and the spelunking package can always load another one.

Comment: @Szabolcs Great, I'll be around in the afternoon!

Comment: @Szabolcs Here is the link for the room: [http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13252/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-istva‌​n](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13252/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-istva‌​n)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the context and file name. However, I still have a problem about the doc of `Get`, which I'll quote here, "If name is the name of a Wolfram Language _context_ , ending with a ` context mark character, then Get will process this name to find the file to read. " My question is, in principle, the context's name can be different with the file name, in this case, there is no way to find the file. I think the right words are, the name before backtick can _only_ be file or directory name, even though it's meant to be context name. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: @luyuwuli That is right. See my edit in the answer that intends to clarify this point.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now, I finally figure this subtlety out.

Answer (score 3):

Just a really quick hack that is nevertheless useful sometimes:

```
LocateFunction[f_]:=(SystemOpen[Context[f]];NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[],f//ToString])
```

If applicable, this opens the package relating to the symbol´s context and primes the search (use <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for subsequent locations of the symbol).

Comment: Actually, `SystemOpen` uses `FindFile` under the hood, so that might be more straightforward to use. My problem with this approach is that it can only point you to the first file loaded in the chain, but there is no way (without actually running `Get`) to know what other files are related. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @IstvánZachar you are absolutely correct. This is just something I cobbled together some time ago on the fly, but it has proven useful mainly for packages of my own doing.