# SymbolicGPU documentation

Tags: symbolic, compile, cudalink, gpu, cuda

I found an interesting files there

```
$CUDALinkPath -> ../GPUTools
```

here

```
Wolfram/WolframEngine/13.0/SystemFiles/Links/GPUTools/SymbolicGPU.m
```

the content looks like if it was a part of complied code of Mathematica to CUDA/OpenCL translator

```
iGPUExpression[Power[x_, Rational[1, 2]], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := CStandardMathOperator[Sqrt, {iGPUExpression[x, opts]}]
iGPUExpression[Power[x_, Rational[-1, 2]], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := COperator[Divide, {1.0, CStandardMathOperator[Sqrt, {iGPUExpression[x, opts]}]}]
iGPUExpression[Power[x_, r:Rational[_, _]], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := CStandardMathOperator[Power, {iGPUExpression[x, opts], iGPUExpression[r, opts]}]
iGPUExpression[Power[x_, 2], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := COperator[Times, {iGPUExpression[x, opts], iGPUExpression[x, opts]}]
iGPUExpression[Power[x_, y_], opts:OptionsPattern[]] := CStandardMathOperator[Power, {iGPUExpression[x, opts], iGPUExpression[y, opts]}]
...
```

Reminds me *SymbolicC* package. Has anyone tried to use this library for something?
Is there a documentation for it?

Comment: It might be part of the new compiler which I believe they are also setting up to work with CUDA.

Comment: Actually it was present back in 2017, so this is just CUDA helper. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41993/82985